# JSF - No reload content

Tags: jsf

folks!
I have a table in JSF `<h:dataTable>` but when I create a new Object (with JPA forward) in my table sometimes it´s shows but sometimes not. I must click in a tab to recharge the content of the xhtml because the new element isn´t shown. Could I reload the page after adding the Object to the list **from the backing bean**?

Thanks for reading and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

you can't control the page from the backing bean except total reload, but if you creates new object on some action, for example a button click, then you can do the following using ajax:

```
<h:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.addNewObject}" value="Add">
  <f:ajax execute="@this" render="tableId" event="click" />
</h:commandButton>
```

If you don't want to use ajax and reload the whole page, then use `action` param of the commandButton:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.addNewObjectAction()}" value="Add"/>
```

where addNewObjectAction returns `null` to reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're storing the list of items for the datatable in the session scope and not reloading it whenever a new item is added. You need to reload it in the action method of adding new item.

```
public void add() {
    saveNewItemInDB(newItem);
    items = reloadListOfItemsFromDB();
}
```